# API query in AngularJS returns nothing, Laravel 5.1 RESTful API, Angular JS (1.5 / 1.4.9) Front End

Tags: angularjs, api, nginx, laravel-5

Wow, I'm at a loss and have been fitting this for days. I could really use some help ...

**PROBLEM :**
When I query my api in Angular Javascript I don't get any data in response. I know the API is working but nothing is attached to the *$scope.data* that I am sending to the view, other *$scope* variables do work. Have attempted to fix the issue using the Angular *$http* Resource and *Restangular* AngJS Service [link](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular). Here are the details of my problem, and thanks for any suggestions.

**CURRENT CONFIG :**
I'm developing a site that uses Laravel 5.1 for a RESTful API. It is located on a local Vagrant instance of Homestead the URL is >> http://api.platspl.at:8000/

I know it works because if I go to >> api.platspl.at:8000/tracks, I get (abbreviated):

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Track 1 Name","slug":"track-1-name",...,"updated_at":"2016-01-31 15:30:56"},{"id":2,...,"updated_at":"2016-01-31 15:30:56"},{"id":3,...,"updated_at":"2016-01-31 15:30:56"}]
```

here is the code for the controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    // Using Model
    //$data = Track::where('published', 1)->get();
    //$data->toJson();
    //return $data;

    // Using DB
    $data = DB::table('tracks')->where('published', 1)->get();
    return response()->json($data);
}
```

as you can see I attempted to fix my Angular JS issue by using both a Laravel Model
and a Database Query, neither fixed anything.

I am using Angular JS for the front-end and there is where my problem lies. When I go to platspl.at:8000/ I receive the Angular App as a response, defined by the routes.php file in Laravel. Here is the routes code:

```
Route::get('/', function() { return View::make('app.index'); });
```

The view I am using is located in /resources/views/app/ and **ALL** the necessary AngularJS files are located in the public directory of the Laravel install. Here is some of the code from the view, followed by the 2 Angular Files referenced in the view.

**VIEW :**

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app="PlatSplatApp">
    <head>...</head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>PlatSpl.at - {{ user }}</h1>
        </div>
        <p>1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}</p>
        <div ng-repeat="track in tracks">
            <h3>{{ track.name }}</h3>
            <p>{{ track.description }}</p>
        </div>
    </body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= asset('app/bower_components/angular/angular.js') ?>"></script> ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= asset('app/bower_components/restangular/src/restangular.js') ?>"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= asset('app/scripts/app.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= asset('app/scripts/controllers/appCtrl.js') ?>"></script>
```

**APP.JS :**

```
angular.module('PlatSplatApp', ['restangular']);
```

**AppCtrl.JS :**

```
angular.module('PlatSplatApp', [])
   .controller('AppCtrl', [ '$scope',
        function($scope, Restangular) {

            // Set User
            $scope.user = 'User Name';

            //Create a Restangular object
            var data = Restangular.allUrl('tracks', 'http://api.platspl.at:8000');

            // make query and return a promise.
            data.getList().then(function(response) {
                $scope.tracks = response;
            });

            //$scope.tracks = Restangular.allUrl('tracks', 'http://api.platspl.at:8000').getList().$object;
            //$scope.tracks = Restangular.allUrl('allTracks', 'http://api.platspl.at:8000/tracks').getList().$object;

            //var data = Restangular.allUrl('tracks', 'http://api.platspl.at:8000/tracks').getList();
            //var data = Restangular.oneUrl('tracks', 'http://api.platspl.at:8000/tracks/by/1').get();
            //$scope.tracks = data;

            //$scope.tracks = [{'name': 'error', 'description': 'error'}];
}]);

// .controller('AppCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http',
//    function ($scope, $http) {
//        $scope.user = 'User Name';
//        $http({
//            method: 'GET',
//            url: 'http://api.platspl.at:8000/tracks',
//        }).then(function(result) {
//            $scope.tracks = result.data;
//        }, function (error) {
//            $scope.tracks = [ { 'name': 'error', 'description': 'error' } ];
//        })
//    }
//]);
```

All the JS coded I attempted to use is commented out. Thanks Again for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Guilty Parties >> **Nginx** & **CORS**

After attempting many suggested solutions this is what I came up with ...

**Laravel API Controller :**

Add

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
```

and

```
public function index()
{
    $data = DB::table('tracks')->where('published', 1)->get();
    return response($data)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
                     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
                     ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type');
}
```

**Angular Controller :**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('PlatSplatApp', [])

 .controller('AppCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {

        var onStatsComplete = function(response)
        {
            $scope.tracks = response.data;
        };
        $http.get("http://api.platspl.at:8000/tracks")
            .then(onStatsComplete);
    }

]);
```

I'll probably teak this solution as I continue work on the site, but  everything snapped into place when I added the headers to the JSON response.

I hope this helps someone and Thanks Again to Wilmer S!

Answer (score 0):

These are the kind of problems that are very hard to debug.

1. Make sure the request is going out to your RESTful API using tools
   like [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Also check that you are getting a response.
2. If the requests are not going out then try using plain old
   `$http.get('url')`
3. If you are getting a response then check response.status and response.data. [Here are the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

You API is definitely working if you can navigate to the URL and get the JSON.

Comment: Thanks Wilmer S for the suggestion. Ultimately, I used the FireFox inspector feature, rt. click and 'Inspect Element'. Under NET I found the following error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://api.platspl.at:8000/tracks. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing). Thanks Again!